# Click to close div

Tags: javascript

I'm using an ad block detector script and would like to make it a bit more user-friendly. Using the following, what script/code do I need to allow the user to click the div to close it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Detect Adblock - Most effective way to detect ad blockers</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <style>
    #iQGIuEqKgDvV {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: #D30000;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="iQGIuEqKgDvV">
      Our website is made possible by displaying online advertisements to our visitors.<br>
      Please consider supporting us by disabling your ad blocker.
    </div>

    <script src="/ads.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    if(!document.getElementById('Ad-Detect-js')){
      document.getElementById('iQGIuEqKgDvV').style.display='block';
    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var slideSource = document.getElementById('slideSource');
document.getElementById('handle').onclick = function(){
  if(!document.getElementById('Ad-Detect-js')){
   slideSource.className = slideSource.className ? 'fade' : 'fade';
  }
}
```

```css
div#slideSource {
opacity:1;
transition: opacity 1s; 
display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: #D30000;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

div#slideSource.fade {
opacity:0;
}
```

```html
 <div id="handle">
    <div id="slideSource">  Our website is made possible by displaying online advertisements to our visitors.<br>
      Please consider supporting us by disabling your ad blocker.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How can it be modified to have the div fade out when closed?

Comment: @DerrickStewart  I just updated my answer to fade out when closed

Comment: Since there is content below the div, is there a way the div can completely disappear so that the content below shifts up in its place? As of now, there's a gap that is the height of the div because it's only hidden.

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: @DerrickStewart yes it is possible. Are you there so we can discuss this and I can help you??

Comment: @DerrickStewart can I use jquery??

Comment: Yes. It's a Wordpress site that has 1.12.4 Here is the site: http://revivedlife.com  @HenryDev

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far! What do you think about the jquery alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Add a event listener to the div, like this:

```
document.getElementById("iQGIuEqKgDvV").addEventListener('click',function(){
    //Your code goes here
    //'this' in this function block represents the current element
    this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

or this:

```
document.getElementById("iQGIuEqKgDvV").onclick = function(){
    //Your code goes here
    //'this' in this function block represents the current element
    this.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Make sure that the element is **loaded** before adding a event listener to the element.

You can also add an `onclick` attribute in your `div` to call a function, like this:

```
<div onclick="hideThis(this)">
```

Then in your script:

```
function hideThis(element){
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
```